# How to know each Chrome Profile correspond to which person

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome allows us to [switch between multiple profiles/people](https://www.howtogeek.com/207614/everything-you-need-to-know-about-google-chromes-profile-switcher/)

Suppose I have 3 people, person 1, person 2 and person 3. Correspondingly, my mac has 3 profiles in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/`, Profile 1, Profile 2 and Profile 3.

How do I know each Chrome Profile correspond to which person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably that's the answer:

"Open Google Chrome in the profile you want to locate the folder for and type chrome://version in the Omnibar"

Source: https://www.addictivetips.com/web/how-to-find-the-user-folder-for-a-specific-chrome-profile/